# How to import javascript code in python with variable?

Tags: python

I have file javascript and python, I want to call javascript function in python code with send variable from python. example my javascript file

```
var msg = 'this is the encrypt key, very long character';
function split (value, msg){
    if(value == msg){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function process(value){
    var a = split(value, msg);
    if (a == "true"){
         return a;
    }else{
         return "Error";
    }
}
```

now I want to add this file to my python code, I want to send variable from python to my javascript code. example like this

```
value = "aaa"
js = open('example.js','r')
print(js.process(value))
```

I want to import javascript file to python code, and I want to use the `process` function in the javascript file. I know my code is wrong, I don't understand how to make a function like that. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need a wonderful module named as js2py. Install by :

> pip install js2py

The code looks like this :

```
import js2py
process=js2py.eval_js('''function process(value,a){
    if (a == "true"){
         return a;
    }else{
         return "Error";
    }
}''')

split=js2py.eval_js('''function split (value){
    var msg = 'this is the encrypt key, very long character';
    if(value == msg){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}''')
value="aaa"
a=split(value)
print(process(value,a))
```